# What are the doctrines of Pratyabhijna school?

Tags: philosophy, agamas, kashmiri-shaivism

One of the major part of kashmir shvia tradition is pratyabhijna or ishwara pratyabhijna.

**What are its fundamental principles?**

Comment: You can read your own answer on the same [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20621/8635)

Comment: Yes i want to specially discuss related to pratyabhijna

Comment: Your answer discusses exactly that, did you read it?

Comment: More detailed oriented answer. That answer has other elements too