# What are six darsanas or philosophies, known to be limbs of Shiva?

Tags: shiva, philosophy, tantra

What are the six **darsanas** or philosophies mentioned in kularnava tantra which are known to be the six limbs of Shiva?

Comment: see 'Introduction' here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62756.html

Comment: Related: [Is there a Darshana/Philosophy based on Agamas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20617/277)

Answer (score 5):

Six Schools of Indian Darshana's are as below:

1. Nyaya
2. Vaishesika
3. Purva Mimamsa
4. Samkhya
5. Yoga
6. Uttra Mimamsa

Here Uttra mimamsa  is Upanishad (Vedic postulate) and Purva mimamsa is vedic text itself (yaga and other vedic literature). Nyaya is Logic which (madhva school of philosophy greatly emphasis) Nyaya Sudha, Nyayaamruta, chandrika, Parimala. Samkhya is numerology and their relation to vedic philosophy. There 2 philosophy here one is asthikia propopunded by Kapila Avatara, and another is nirishwara sankhya propounded by Kapila rishi. All know about Panthajali and Hatha yoga. only left is Vaishesikia  that is metaphysics its about how the universe is composed off atomic nature.

There were other schools of taughts like Charvaka, Pashupatha, Jaina, Buddha All rejects Vedic authority. Like Nasthika Samkhya.  So they are not considered.

Comment: The question is talking about Shad Darshanas which are known to be limbs of Shivas as per Tantra.

Comment: Shiva is talking about these same 6 Darshanas. @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross Hmm. The names mentioned in TheLittleNaruto's answer are different. If they're same as mentioned in this answer means just names are different?

Comment: No, the Kularnava in the Tantra verse Lord Shiva is talking about the six darshanas as his 6 limbs and there the 6 darshanas are the usual ones not those mentioned in Naruto's answer. @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross Can we continue further discussion in [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)?

Comment: In the room "Room for Ram and Rickross" we can @Pandya

Answer (score 4):

As per [Parshurama Kalpa Sutras, By Dr. Param Hans Mishra](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/parashuram-kalpa-sutra-NZF962/), Bhagwan Shiva himself created Six Darshanas; they are:

1. Shaiva Darshana
2. Vaishnava Darshana
3. Bramha Darshana
4. Saur Darshana
5. Shakta Darshana
6. Baudhdha Darshana

Since the book is in Hindi, used Google Translator for English translation:

> Apart from these, six darshans are also Bhagavatpravart. **By whom real darshana happens, it is called darshana. These six are considered - 1. Shaivadarshan, 2. Vaishnavadarshan, 3. Brahmadarshan, 4. Sauradarshan, 5. Shaktadarshan and 6. Bauddhadarshana.** By establishing Panini, Vyasa, etc., Paramashivabhattaraka changed all the disciplines, scriptures and philosophies in this way. In this, he did not have to do any Ayas, but it was accomplished by Lilah.

Comment: Now I don't have the book with me. Will update the answer with limbs related info.

Comment: U can answer when u go to bangalore 

Comment: Hmm. So, Shad Darshana by Shiva is different from what is usually known as [Shad Darshana](https://dharmawiki.org/index.php/Shad_Darshanas_(%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF))

Comment: @Pandya yes that's as per the book I have.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto are those Darshanas known to be limbs of Shiva as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Pandya I'll confirm once I go back to the city. :)